# Generate different docpad collections for different languages

Tags: docpad

I want to tune my multilungual DocPad blog so that pages ended with *.ru.md go into /ru/ directory, and pages ended with *.en.md go into /en/ directory.

Let's say this is the initial structire

```
src/
  pages/
    page1.ru.md
    page1.en.md
    page2.ru.md
```

And this is what I want:

```
./
  en/
    page1.html
  ru/
    page1.html
    page2.html
```

`./` because I am going to host with `gh-pages`.

And the same for posts. I would like to store them in

```
src/
  posts/
    post-about-docpad.ru.md
    post-about-docpad.en.md
```

And get

```
./
  en/
    posts/
      post-about-docpad.html
  ru/
    posts/
      post-about-docpad.html
```

How should I config docpad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st step is renaming your documents to use a dash for the language like so: `page1-en.html`, and `page1-ru.html`, instead of `page1.en.html` and `page1.ru.tml` — as otherwise as @kizu correctly points out, it will cause problems as DocPad renders from extension to extension.

Once that is done, you can add the following to your docpad configuration file:

```
collections:

    # Fetch documents in different languages
    translate: (database) ->
        languageRegex = /^(.+?)-(en|ru)$/
        #docpadOutPath = @getConfig().outPath
        @getCollection('documents').findAllLive({basename: languageRegex}).on 'add', (document) ->
            # Prepare
            a = document.attributes

            parts = a.basename.match(languageRegex)
            basename = parts[1]
            language = parts[2]

            relativeOutPath = "#{language}/#{a.relativeOutDirPath}/#{basename}.#{a.outExtension}"
            #outPath = "#{docpadOutPath}/#{relativeOutPath}"

            urls = ["/#{relativeOutPath}"]

            # Apply
            document
                .setMetaDefaults({
                    #outPath
                    url: urls[0]
                })
                .addUrl(urls)
```

This will have URLs working in the way you want.

Then run DocPad in the static environment with the cleanurls plugin installed, to write the documents to the desired locations.

```
docpad install cleanurls
docpad generate --env static
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be done, but with three changes in the file structure:

1. As dots in DocPad's path are there to delimit the different renderers and I'm not sure how to do what I'd propose inside a renderer, so it won't throw `Rendering the extension … didn't do anything.` error,  I propose to use the `_en`/`_ru` instead of `.en`/`.ru`, this way you could then do stuff based on filenames without any extra hassle.
2. It is better to use the Docpad's initial paths, i.e. put your `pages` and `blog` folders inside `documents` folder.
3. There could be a way to use the files without the `.html.md` part, but as it is a DocPad way, you should use it.

Maybe there are ways to do what you want this without those changes, but it would be less trivial :)

So, the code to place at `docpadConfig` in `docpad.coffee` (here is an [example project at GitHub](https://github.com/kizu/docpad-test)):

```
docpadConfig = {
    collections:
        # Declare `ru` and `en` collections
        ruDocuments: ->
            @getCollection("documents").findAllLive({
                basename: /_ru$/
            })
        enDocuments: ->
            @getCollection("documents").findAllLive({
                basename: /_en$/
            })

    events:
        renderBefore: () ->
            # Rewrite `pages/` to the root and `posts/` to the `blog/`.
            this.docpad.getCollection('documents').forEach (page) ->
                newOutPath = page.get('outPath')
                    .replace('/out/pages/', '/out/')
                    .replace('/out/posts/', '/out/blog/')
                newUrl = page.get('url')
                    .replace('pages/', '')
                    .replace('posts/', 'blog/')
                page.set('outPath', newOutPath)
                page.setUrl(newUrl)

            # Rewrite `_ru` to the `/ru/`
            this.docpad.getCollection('ruDocuments').forEach (page) ->
                newOutPath = page.get('outPath')
                    .replace('/out/', '/out/ru/')
                    .replace('_ru.', '.')
                newUrl = '/ru' + page.get('url')
                page.set('outPath', newOutPath)
                page.setUrl(newUrl)

            # Rewrite `_en` to the `/en/`
            this.docpad.getCollection('enDocuments').forEach (page) ->
                newOutPath = page.get('outPath')
                    .replace('/out/', '/out/en/')
                    .replace('_en.', '.')
                page.set('outPath', newOutPath)
                newUrl = '/en' + page.get('url').replace('_en.', '.')
                page.setUrl(newUrl)
}
module.exports = docpadConfig
```

At first we declare two collections: one for all ru documents and another for all en documents.

Then we at first rewrite the `pages/` to the root, and then rewrite the `_en`/`_ru` files to `/en/` and `/ru/`.

Note that the changes are only how the source files are stored, the resulting output would be the same as you want in your question.

So, instead of

```
src/
  pages/
    page1.ru.md
    page1.en.md
    page2.ru.md
  posts/
    post-about-docpad.ru.md
    post-about-docpad.en.md
```

You should write this way:

```
src/
  documents/
    pages/
      page1_ru.html.md
      page1_en.html.md
      page2_ru.html.md
    posts/
      post-about-docpad_ru.html.md
      post-about-docpad_en.html.md
```

But you would get you desired output just as you need. The only thing is that I didn't understand the part about the `gh-pages`: are you going to store the result and the source in the same branch? I'd propose to use the `master` for the source and the `gh-pages` for the result.

But if you'd need to have only one branch, well, ok, you can easy rewrite all the things you'd like by replacing `.replace('/out/', '/out/ru/')` with `.replace('/out/', '/ru/')` etc. — this would put the rendered files up to one level above `out`.